# gqlgen websocket not close if initFunc returns an error

Tags: go, websocket, graphql, gqlgen

I'm using [gqlgen](https://gqlgen.com/) for my GraphQL API and I have some subscription (websocket) in my API. But it's not working as expected:

When `initFunc` of the `transport.Websocket{}` return an error the websocket is not close but spam the init function.

I would have expected the websocket to be closed and only one request is made to the server.

How can I can properly close the websocket if the init function failed (for instance auth failed) ?

---

Here is an example of an init funct that have this issue. It is from the [gqlgen websocket example](https://github.com/99designs/gqlgen/tree/master/_examples/websocket-initfunc/server). I just added a debug print to make things clear in the webSocketInit:

```
func webSocketInit(ctx context.Context, initPayload transport.InitPayload) (context.Context, error) {
    // Get the token from payload
    any := initPayload["authToken"]
    token, ok := any.(string)
    if !ok || token == "" {
        fmt.Println("error in init")
        return nil, errors.New("authToken not found in transport payload")
    }

    // Perform token verification and authentication...
    userId := "john.doe" // e.g. userId, err := GetUserFromAuthentication(token)

    // put it in context
    ctxNew := context.WithValue(ctx, "username", userId)

    return ctxNew, nil
}
```

and then just run a query in the playground without any auth header:

```
subscription test {
  subscribe(subscriber:"jj")
}
```

the browser will be hanging in a loading cycle and the server is looping in the init function:

```
➜  websocket_gqlgen ./server                                  
2022/12/20 09:40:56 connect to http://localhost:8080/ for GraphQL playground
error in init
error in init
error in init
error in init
error in init
...
```

The complete server and gql schema can be found in the [gqlgen example repo](https://github.com/99designs/gqlgen/tree/master/_examples/websocket-initfunc/server) but here is the main function copy paste for your convenience:

```
const defaultPort = "8080"

func main() {
    port := os.Getenv("PORT")
    if port == "" {
        port = defaultPort
    }

    router := chi.NewRouter()

    // CORS setup, allow any for now
    // https://gqlgen.com/recipes/cors/
    c := cors.New(cors.Options{
        AllowedOrigins:   []string{"*"},
        AllowCredentials: true,
        Debug:            false,
    })

    srv := handler.New(graph.NewExecutableSchema(graph.Config{Resolvers: &graph.Resolver{}}))
    srv.AddTransport(transport.POST{})
    srv.AddTransport(transport.Websocket{
        KeepAlivePingInterval: 10 * time.Second,
        Upgrader: websocket.Upgrader{
            CheckOrigin: func(r *http.Request) bool {
                return true
            },
        },
        InitFunc: func(ctx context.Context, initPayload transport.InitPayload) (context.Context, error) {
            return webSocketInit(ctx, initPayload)
        },
    })
    srv.Use(extension.Introspection{})

    router.Handle("/", playground.Handler("My GraphQL App", "/app"))
    router.Handle("/app", c.Handler(srv))

    log.Printf("connect to http://localhost:%s/ for GraphQL playground", port)
    log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":"+port, router))

}
```